# Java - ListIterator Implementation Specifics

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I have a quick question about how ListIterators (and, I guess, Iterators in general) perform in Java. For, say, a Linked List (Java's standard one), if I get a ListIterator for it, does it loop through the entire list to build it? I'm using this to implement a fairly standard hash table, and I'm worried that using an iterator as opposed to writing a class of my own to do it would hamper my performance to O(n) always, as opposed to at worst.

Comment: How do you use a List to "implement a fairly standard hash table"? How are lists and hash tables related?

Comment: @LutzHorn Standard implementation of a [Hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is an array of "hash buckets" and each bucket is a linked list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building a `ListIterator` does not iterate over the `List`. It's essentially just initializing the current position in the list.

And that position is updated whenever you call `.next()`.

Example implementation in [`LinkedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr)

```
private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Node<E> lastReturned = null;
    private Node<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;

    ListItr(int index) {
        // assert isPositionIndex(index);
        next = (index == size) ? null : node(index);
        nextIndex = index;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextIndex < size;
    }

    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        lastReturned = next;
        next = next.next;
        nextIndex++;
        return lastReturned.item;
    }
```

And [`ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr)

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
```

It is no requirement that constructing an `Iterator` is free. Imagine a Tree: Iterating over it could be implemented by building a linear representation first and then iterating that list. (I don't know of such an implementation though) That would be O(N) for construction, O(1) per `.next()`

Alternatively you could search the next element each time: that would be a O(log N) operation for each `.next()` but O(1) for creation. (Java's `TreeMap` does that)

Another option is to build a stack/heap of nodes to visit as you go. Guava's [TreeTraverser](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html) uses this approach. Should be O(1) per `.next()` and O(1) for initialization.

Comment: interesting examples, but im not sure where some of the vars such as size come from? I take it this is more just for illustrative purposes and pseudo code..

Comment: @Opentuned, size refers to ArrayList's size. And this is indeed the actual code I'm seeing in JDK 8.